# How do you add a variable to a grep -P regex lookaround?

Tags: regex, bash, perl, variables, grep

I'm trying to create a text-based game in bash, and I need my script to look through a file and display a specific section onto the terminal using delimiters and a regex lookaround. A slight problem is that I only started learning bash this year so I'm still not very efficient with my coding; so apologies for the crudeness. My problem is is follows:

here is a modified snippet of the file I want to search through:

```
"MENU>2>8"

{

\e[1m\e[33m1\e[21m \e[37m- \e[33mOption one.
\n\e[1m2\e[21m \e[37m- \e[33mOption two.
\n\e[1m3\e[21m \e[37m- \e[33mOption three.

}
```

The title is what I grep for inside the quotation, the first number after it is the menu number because there are multiple (assigned to the variable `$MENU_NUM`), and the second number is the field used to find said title. The code may make more sense than me trying to explain it:

```
TEXT=$(cat ~/Desktop/Dialogue.txt | tr "\n" " ")

MENU_NUM=2

echo -en $(echo "$TEXT" | grep -Po '(?<=MENU>[^$MENU_NUM]>)[0-9]+"  {.*' | grep -Po '(?<={ ).*' | grep -Po '^(.*?)}' | head -c-3)
```

I realise it looks awful with all the piping, but I couldn't get it to work with one grep without it outputting EVERYTHING after the lookbehind. I'm not too fussed with whether or not it's convoluted, the only thing I can't get to work is the variable. No matter what I try, it will not read `$MENU_NUM`.
I've tried:

```
\$MENU_NUM
^$MENU_NUM
/^$MENU_NUM/
\^$MENU_NUM/
^${MENU_NUM}
```

and tons of other variations but it just will not read that number.
Just to clarify, if I use a number, it works. For example, if I use:

```
echo -en $(echo "$TEXT" | grep -Po '(?<=MENU>2>)[0-9]+"  {.*' | grep -Po '(?<={ ).*' | grep -Po '^(.*?)}' | head -c-3)
```

I get:

```
1 - Option one.
2 - Option two.
3 - Option three.
```

in the right colour and formatting.

I hope someone can help me out with this as I was really getting into bash; but this is annoying me quite a lot. And regex help pages on the Internet are so full of technical language that I just get confused and it makes it even more irksome.

> EDIT

Thanks to the help of *chrisaycock* I was able to modify my code substantially. What follows is the outcome:

```
 $ echo -en $(echo "$TEXT" | grep -Po "\"MENU>$MENU_NUM>[0-9]+\"  {.*?}" | grep -Po '(?<={ ).*' | head -c-3)
 1 - Option one.
 2 - Option two.
 3 - Option three.
```

Just like it should be.

Now it now only uses two greps and seems to work with other sections of the file too. I kept the `$TEXT` variable in as it's necessary for my script in other sections. Thanks again.

Comment: Variables don't interpolate inside single quotes, so `foo=bar; echo '$foo'` will print `$foo`, not `bar`. There's probably an easier way to do this...what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you just want to print everything inside the curly braces following the specified `MENU>` line?

Comment: I want to only take everything between the curly braces, nothing outside. But because there are lots of instances of them within the file itself, it makes it difficult telling `grep` which one I want. I didn't know that about the single quotes though. Can I use `grep -P` with double quotes instead?

Comment: Tip: `(?<=...)...` can be written as `...\K...`, which also allows "variable-length" patterns.

Comment: Oh. That is a great help, thanks. Variable-length lookbehinds was such a pain when using `[0-9]+`, that's why it was in a new `grep`. I don't need it any more, but I will remember the tip for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use *single quotes* in bash with variables; use *double quotes* instead.

I had to make some changes to your grep statement since I couldn't get it to work on my system. Here's an example that uses process substitution and redirection to obviate the need for `cat` or one-time-use variables.

```
echo -en $(grep -Po "\"MENU>$MENU_NUM>[0-9]+\"  {.*" <(tr "\n" " " < Dialogue.txt) | grep -Po '(?<={ ).*' | grep -Po '^(.*?)}' | head -c-3)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much, that worked perfectly. Hopefully I'll be able to use that with all the other sections of the file too. =D Sorry I can't vote you up yet. I need 15 reputation, and I've only just joined.